# How can I know which versions of Jmeter are obsolete and are no longer supported?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'am using Apache Jmeter 5.3 for load testing purpose and someone has asked me the question that 1.What is the end of life and support of Jmeter 5.3?
I have gone through the Apache official site but couldn't find this information.
Can someone answer this.
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should "go through the Apache official site" once again, the [first chapter of JMeter Best Practices states](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)

> **16.1 Always use latest version of JMeter**
>
> The performance of JMeter is being constantly improved, so users are highly encouraged to use the most up to date version.
> Ensure you always read changes list to be aware of new improvements and components. **You should absolutely avoid using versions that are older than 3 versions before the last one.**

For instance fix for the [CVE-2021-45105](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-45105) hasn't been backported and is present in JMeter 5.4.3 and onwards so using JMeter 5.3 you're placing your load generators at risk so I would recommend upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)) on next available opportunity.